# Mysql delete from table where appears only once

Tags: mysql

I want to delete rows from my table which only appear once.
I have try this but it gave me error.

```
delete from trans where nol in (select nol from trans T1 group by T1.nol having count(*) = 1)
```

Comment: post error message , which error you get while executing this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
For workaround, you need to wrap your subquery into a table alias.

Sample query:

```
delete from trans 
where nol in (SELECT nol FROM
    (select nol from trans T1 group by T1.nol having count(*) = 1) t)
```